# Question about the use of Plex - where should it go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask this question:

> I'm thinking about getting a personal server to backup files from my computer and to stream media. [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/) looks like a good option to stream media, however if I use this software can I also backup other non-media files? Nothing I've found has mentioned the possibility of just using plex or something else, it seems like there are media servers or backup servers. Is there additional software that I can run in parallel, or software that can backup files and stream media?

Where can I ask such question?

**Note**: I would like to know if X supports Y (about plex) but can't seem to find an answer, also I can't find any websites that mention using a single server to both stream media and back up files, it's always one or the other. I don't know if I'm not searching the right terms or if it isn't possible at all.

**EDIT**: What I really want to know is if a personal server can run multiple applications (Plex, a backup application service, and maybe a file sharing application)? Since having a single service be able to do all of that doesn't seem possible based on my findings.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you need something that does both? We use Plex on our NAS but for video but it doesn't prevent us from using the NAS for other storage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you want to ask if software X supports Y. That seems a general software use question to me, which should go on Super User.

Make sure to show you have invested time to get the answer yourself.

You also want to watch you are not asking to recommend software or hardware, which is off-topic there. Software or Hardware Recommendations might be the place for such questions, however you should formulate it very clear what exactly you want.

Comment: I would like to know if X supports Y (about plex) but can't seem to find an answer, also I can't find any websites that mention using a single server to both stream media and back up files, it's always one or the other. I don't know if I'm not searching the right terms or if it isn't possible at all

Comment: There is a Plex tag here: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plex